# Your org doesn't have access to component forceChatter:recordFeedContainer

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, source-push

I am trying to run:

```
sfdx force:source:push
```

To a new scratch org, but I am getting this error on a few of the metadata items:

> Your org doesn't have access to component forceChatter:recordFeedContainer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get rid of the error message by opening the scratch org and enabling `Chatter`:

```
Setup > Chatter > Chatter Settings = Enable
```

Alternatively, create the scratch org with `Chatter` already enabled:

```
{
  "orgName": "Org Name",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": [],
  "orgPreferences": {
    "enabled": ["ChatterEnabled"],
  }
}
```

Note the `orgPreferences > enabled > ChatterEnabled`

Or

```
{
  "orgName": "Org Name",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": [],
  "settings": {
    "chatterSettings": { "enableChatter" : true },
  }
}
```

Note the `settings > chatterSettings > enableChatter = true`

Comment: +1;  really appreciate the contribution to the corpus of knowledge via your self-answered questions